# Creating custom variables/attributes in Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a custom attribute inside of a Laravel Model. This attribute would be the same for all of the Model instances (static?).  The goal is to use this attribute to populate a select dropdown when creating a Model instance. Example:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $guarded = [ 'id' ];
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $genders = ['male'=>'Male', 'female'=>'Female'];  //custom

    public static function getGenderOptions() {
        return $genders;
    }
}
```

Then when building out the form, I could do something like:

```
// UserController.php
$data['select_options'] = User::getGenderOptions();
return view('user.create', $data);

// create.blade.php
{!! Form::select( 'gender', $select_options ) !!}
```

This causes me to get the error:

```
Undefined variable: genders
```

I am trying to prevent cluttering my Controller with all of the select options, as there are also a few others I haven't included.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify Your `protected $genders` element and make it public+static. So then You can access it directly like so: `User::$genders`.

But...my personal decision would be to move constants to config file or some kind of helper.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Right now these options are only being used for the Users, but if they start being used elsewhere, then I would plan to move them to some sort of config.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be

```
public function getGenderOptions() {
    return $this->genders;
}
```

Or simply declare `$genders` as a static variable and use `return self::$genders`

Check the docs - [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and [Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: Also Visibility and Scope resolution docs might be helpful:
http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.visibility
http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim

Comment: don't think `$this->genders` would work inside the model, as it has to be in the object instance, correct?  But I did end up using `self::$genders`, after declaring `$genders` as `public static`, as suggested by @Giedrius Kiršys

Comment: Well, with `$this->genders` it can be used as `$data['select_options'] = (new User())->getGenderOptions();`
but if you want to use it statically, then yes, you should declare `$genders` as `static`.  
Btw, if you are going to extend your class `User` and change `$genders` value in a new class, then you should use `static` instead of `self`: `return static::$gender`